# finding continuous signal in noisy binary time series

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, smoothing

Suppose I have a time series such as:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 , 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and I know there is some noise in the signal. I want to remove the noise as best I can and still output a binary signal. The above example would turn into something like:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I have implemented a naive rule-based approach where I iterate through the values and have some minimum amount of `1`s or `0`s I need to "swap" the signal.

It seems like there must be a better way to do it. A lot of the results from googling around give non-binary output. Is there some scipy function I could leverage for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two similar functions that can help you: [scipy.signal.argrelmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmin.html#scipy.signal.argrelmin) and [scipy.signal.argrelmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmax.html#scipy.signal.argrelmax). There are search for local min/max in discrete arrays. You should pass your array and neighbours search radius as `order`. Your problem can be solved by their combination:

```
>>> a = np.asarray([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 , 1, 1, 1, 1], int)

>>> signal.argrelmin(a, order=3)
(array([4], dtype=int32),)

>>> signal.argrelmax(a, order=3)
(array([15], dtype=int32),)
```

Then you can just replace these elements.

Comment: wow cool function! I see it even works if I extend the input to have multiple mins or maxes. This would not be extensible to non-binary signal though it looks like